# Validating one property at a time using ko.validation

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm using [ko.validation](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation) and, previously, I was using it to validate an entire view model at a time. Now, I am splitting the view model up into pieces and I need to be able to validate one or a couple properties at a time. I have several custom validators, so I'd rather not just switch to completely manual validation. Is there a way to use ko.validation to validate just one property at a time?

Answer (score 1):

This is an increasingly common issue with view models that need to be re-used in multiple views, or when one view requires multiple instances of the same view model, but with differing validation requirements (references in comments). Knockout and Knockout-Validation are pretty awesome, but the current implementations do not yet scale well to these reusability scenarios.

My recently-open-sourced project 'ValidatedViewModel' developed while working for [Extreme Engineeering Solutions](http://www.xes-inc.com/) provides a means to structure the application of validation constraint groups on an instance-basis. Clone [Validated View Model here on github](https://github.com/carlschroedl/validatedviewmodel). Please let me know what you think of the documentation, unit tests, and functionality.

Comment: [1]: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/knockoutjs/9JJPlk-9vu4/FQUR1_m5Os8J
  [2]: https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/issues/111